# `save_post` hook called on inserting new post from front end

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a front end form which creates a new post in a custom post type and adds some meta data to the post.
I am submitting the form by checking for `$_POST` values in the same page in which form is created.

```
if( isset($_POST['save_form']) ){
    $post_info = ''; // Set values to variables
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_info );
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'my_key', $form_field, true);
}
```

Recently i have found that `save_post_{post_type}` hook is fired whenever i submit this form. So all the fields in the front end form are available inside the callback function. 
Is this default or have i done something wrong ? Should i change the saving method since posted values are available in `save_post_{post_type}` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is the default and yes you should be doing your work inside the save_post_{post_type} action. That's exactly what it is there for and is its intended use. Be careful, though, as this action is called **every time** the post is "saved" (created *or* updated)!

Comment: Is `save_post_{post_type}` intended to update a post type from backend only ? Can the same hook be used to save data from front end ? The reason i am asking is that , of all the tutorials i have seen, they just access `$_POST` and use the posted data to insert a post using `wp_insert_post`

Comment: Good question. No, it is not intended to be used on the backend only. It is, perhaps, a more granular approach than `wp_insert_post()`. I think the main difference, as I said in my post, is that `save_post_{post_type}` runs _every_ time the post is saved, whether it is being inserted or being updated. This can trip you up quite easily and is perhaps why most tutorials use `wp_insert_post()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. This is something that most tutorials lack.